# How to get $\nabla p=\nabla (-\Delta)^{-1} \nabla \cdot (u\cdot \nabla u)$ from the Navier-Stokes equations?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

The incompressible Navier-Stokes equations are given by:

$$u_t + u \cdot \nabla u -\Delta u + \nabla p=0,\qquad \text{div } u=0,$$ where $u$ is the velocity field and $p$ is the pressure.

Here is a fact that I don't know why it's true from the above equations: 
$$\nabla p=\nabla (-\Delta)^{-1} \nabla \cdot (u\cdot \nabla u).$$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what is $(-\Delta)^{-1}$?

Comment: @Jack I just know it's the inverse of Laplacian operator. Maybe it's not enough, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, you have the so called pressure poisson equation:
$$
-\Delta p=\nabla\cdot((u\cdot\nabla)u)\tag{1}
$$

Now applying the inverse of $-\Delta$ on both sides, you get
$$
p=(-\Delta)^{-1}\nabla\cdot((u\cdot\nabla)u)
$$
and thus
$$
\nabla p=\nabla(-\Delta)^{-1}\nabla\cdot((u\cdot\nabla)u)
$$

---

To see how to get (1), consider
$$
\nabla\cdot(u_t+(u\cdot\nabla)u)=\nabla\cdot(\Delta u-\nabla p)
$$
and use the divergence-free condition for $u$. On the LHS, you have
$$
\partial_t(\nabla\cdot u)+\nabla\cdot((u\cdot\nabla)u)=0+\nabla\cdot((u\cdot\nabla)u)
$$
On the RHS, you have
$$
\Delta(\nabla\cdot u)-\Delta p=-\Delta p.
$$